# What is the recommended way of dealing with a customer class with dozens(about 50) of attributes in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop

I have a **Customer** class that has about 50 attributes(customer details).
Leaving the customer class in it's bare form, I fear of bloating the constructor with so many attributes.
I can however group these details into categories: **personal**, **employee**, **medical** etc.

But I don't know whether grouping those details into separate classes is an efficient approach, Just thinking.

This is how the attributes in the class looks like:

```
class Insuree{

    protected $_photoUrl;
    protected $_refNumber;
    protected $_surName;
    protected $_otherName;
    protected $_postalAddress;
    protected $_email;
    protected $_phoneNumber;
    protected $_gender;
    protected $_occupation;
    protected $_residentialAddress;
    protected $_maritalStatus;
    protected $_placeOfBirth;
    protected $_dateOfBirth;
    protected $_idType; //Passport, Drivers license, biometric etc
    protected $_nameOfEmployer;
    protected $_addressOfEmployer;
    protected $_phoneNumberOfEmployer;
    protected $_emailOfEmployer;
    protected $_paymentMode;
    protected $_accountNumber;
    protected $_beneficiarySurName;
    protected $_beneficiaryFirstName;
    protected $_beneficiaryDateOfBirth;
    protected $_beneficiaryPhoneNumber;
    protected $_bank;

    function __construct(){}
}

class CashPlan extends Insuree
{

    function __construct()
    {
        # code...
   }
}

class HomeGoingPlan extends Insuree
{

    function __construct()
    {
        # code...
    }
}
```

I think the above info will give a gist of what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: How should we know without seeing any of this data?

Comment: Oh, you mean pasting the full class's attributes, about 50  here?

Comment: Why not?.......

Comment: You can have only one associative array where you store attributes, and use the overloading functions to use the attribute names on the object directly, also controlling if the attribute could be read or not. This way the number of attributes are also flexible. Please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Answer (score 0):

Keep attributes (data) private, objects are defined by what they do; not how they do it.

If you're concerned about initialization taking too long and doing too much I suggest passing an object with the responsibility of dealing with the database in the constructor. That way your Insuree implementation can consult the database as needed to perform whatever duties it has.

```
interface MyAppDatabase {

    public function fetchPersonalInfo();
    public function fetchMedicalInfo();

}

class Insuree
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(MyAppDatabase $d)
    {
        $this->db = $d;
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the Insuree class is a base class, that is why its members are protected. CashPlan and  HomePlan will be extending it. And  these details(attribute values) are yet to be entered onto the Database through a register() method. Can the fetchPersonInfo(), and fetchMedicalInfo() methods in the interface be implemented in a way that will cater for both cases? ie. fetching from the user input fields and fetching from the Database?